# Finding differences between files (xlsx) due to SAP BI update

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, vbscript

I am at work testing a new version for our frontend dwh (SAP BI 4.2 -> 4.3). I realized that the exported excel files seem to work differently now. They are still .xlsx files and look the same, but existing vbs scripts don't work anymore when it comes to pasting data.
The error that always occurs is:

> This action won't work on multiple selections

One simple code example where this error occurs is:

```
For i = 4 To 29
objInput.Worksheets("Worksheet").Range("D"&i&":M"&i).Copy
objWorkbook.Worksheets("Worksheet").Range("D"&i&":M"&i).PasteSpecial -4163, -4142, False, False
```

The cells only have numbers, nothing more. And it is always the PasteSpecial line causing the error.

As I said, I can't find any differences in the exported excel files (4.1 vs 4.2), but I saw that in one case for example the "new" file is 19kb big - the old one (working for the script) is 18,9kb.

Is there any way to find out what the difference is between the two files? Or does anyone know why this error in vbs is now occurring?

Comment: is there any cells hidden in the range in any of the workbooks?

Comment: No, there is nothing hidden

Comment: VBS or VBA? Can you `PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`?

Comment: Create a macro, do a paste special, then inspect the code and verify the differences. That should reveal the differences.

Comment: Also I noticed you are using a For, Loop. If that's so, you don't need to use Copy since you don't want the formatting, only the values. Right? So use `Workbook--Cells.Range("D"&i&":M"&i).Value = Input--Cells.Range("D"&i&":M"&i).Value` with correct coding of course but that's the idea.

Comment: It is VBS, not VBA, so xlPasteValues does not work. Regarding the copy pasting in the for loop: didn't think of that, this is working now in this case, thanks. However, the above mentioned problem occurs also in other scripts with PasteSpecial, where the formatting is also needed. I found out that using the Copy + PasteSpecial works inside both files, i.e. copying 3 values in the same file and sheet to other cells. But if I want to copy and paste just 3 numbers from one file to another (even if it is a copy of the "new" file) then the above error occurs again.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. Simply was because of a bugged SAP BI export; adding tabs for example didn't work either before (same multiple selection error).

Comment: We are experiencing the same symptoms. Did you resolve the issue / what steps did you do to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems with a generated Excel file from a tool. I couldn't add or delete sheets. I couldn't copy and paste values. It kept giving the error "This action won't work on multiple selections" even though I didn't have multiple selections.

After much investigation, I found out that there was a VeryHidden sheet (not the same as Hidden). After I made that deleted that problematic sheet, then everything worked fine afterwards.

You can try unhiding the sheet with Developer > Visual Basic. Or you can delete it programmatically using vba/vbscript or openpyxl.